# Dynamic view in Sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, javascript

Im Trying to achieve a hierarchal view permission on a Sharepoint custom list. A manager / employee relationship, where a manager in the top hierarchy can see all the employees/managers lists items in the Sharepoint. However a manager/employee below cannot see the lists items of the manager/employee above him.

Here is an image to illustrate what i am trying to achieve.

[image]

So M1 should be able to see all the list items in this Sharepoint list. and on the other side for example M5 will only be able to see M4 & M6.

I have done some search only for something dynamic but it was very basic by using the [Me] and [Today] which does not work for this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SharePoint does not handle scenarios like these very well. As the name implies, SharePoint is meant for sharing, not for restricting access.

If your hierarchy is built with folders, you can achieve the permissions by creating groups for each folder and adding the group members for each group.

Since SharePoint groups cannot be nested, you can use AD security groups, which CAN be nested, to define the group members and use AD group names instead of individual people in the SharePoint groups.

Answer (score 1):

Just as teylyn said, SharePoint does not support a hierarchical tree for permission groups. You can add folders to build a similar hierarchy while I think you will need to create unique permissions in each level.

Or you can consider creating separate lists with different groups. M1 is a site level manager while M2 and M3 only has permission on certain list. However the idea does not change.